# Get unique values from array with specific filtering

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.6

Sorry about the pretty bad title, I'm not a native speaker and wasn't sure how to phrase this.

Here is my problem:

I have a very long array with this format:

```
$array = array(
    'key1.value1' => '1',
    'key1.value2' => '0',
    'key1.value3' => '1',
    'key2.value1' => '0',
    'key2.value2' => '0',
    'key3.value1' => '1'
);
```

From this array, I would like to get another one with this format:

```
$newArray = array(
   'key1' => array(
        'value1' => '1',
        'value2' => '0',
        'value3' => '1'
    ),
    'key2' => array(
        'value1' => '0',
        'value2' => '0'
    ),
    'key3' => array(
        'value1' => '1'
    )
);
```

I have tried a few methods but really didn't find any solution that isn't extremely long, so I wondered if I could any tips/tricks to get this done easily!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can try to use `in_array(string, $array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    'key1.value1' => '1',
    'key1.value2' => '0',
    'key1.value3' => '1',
    'key2.value1' => '0',
    'key2.value2' => '0',
    'key3.value1' => '1'
);

$Results = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $KeyValue = explode(".",$key);
    if(!isset($Results[$KeyValue[0]])){
        $Results[$KeyValue[0]] = array();
    }
    $Results[$KeyValue[0]][end($KeyValue)] = $value;
}
print_r($Results);
```

Comment: i've see that only create a 1 second level?. Could be?

Comment: @Álvaro Touzón this should give the chap the format he needs.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$generate = [];
foreach($array  as $key=>$val ){
list($first, $second) = split('.', $key);
if(!isset($genrate[$first]){
$genrate[$first] = [];
if(!$genrate[$first][$second]){
$genrate[$first][$second]= [];
}
}
$genrate[$first][$second] = $val;
}
```

Expect it helps.
Tks

Comment: $val or $value needs to change

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `explode()` function:

```
$transformed = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $pair = explode('.', $k);
    $transformed[$pair[0]][$pair[1]] = $v;
}

print_r($transformed);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 1
            [value2] => 0
            [value3] => 1
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 0
            [value2] => 0
        )

    [key3] => Array
        (
            [value1] => 1
        )
)
```